# Fill empty cells in column with value of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a HC list in which every entry should have an ID, but some entries do not have an ID. I would like to fill those empty cells by combining the the first name column and the last name column.
How would I go about this? I tried googling for fillna and the like but couldn't get it to work.
What I want is basically this:

```
If hc["ID"] == "": 
    hc["ID"] = hc["First Name"] + hc["Last Name"]
```

Comment: Are these values `NaN` or literally an empty string? if `NaN` then `hc.loc[hc["ID"].isnull(),'ID'] =  hc["First Name"] + hc["Last Name"]` otherwise `hc.loc[hc["ID"] == '','ID'] =  hc["First Name"] + hc["Last Name"]`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `loc` and a boolean mask if `NaN` then:

```
hc.loc[hc["ID"].isnull(),'ID'] = hc["First Name"] + hc["Last Name"]
```

otherwise for empty string:

```
hc.loc[hc["ID"] == '','ID'] = hc["First Name"] + hc["Last Name"]
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. I have just one question. It seems like it is actually NaN, since your first solution worked. I would have guessed that they are actually empty string. How can I discern between empty string & NaN?

Comment: You can do `df['ID'].isnull()` this will return a boolean series telling you which entries are really `NaN`, similarly `df['ID'] == ''`

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative, you can also use `fillna()` if not dealing with strings:

`hc['ID'].fillna(hc['First Name'] + hc['Last Name'], inplace=True)`

docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html